# Как получить верхнее модальное окно в WinForms?

Tags: c#, winapi, vb.net, winworms

Для программы пишется плагин с использованием WinForms.

В программе открыто модальное окно. Надо ещё открыть своё модальное окно так, чтобы окно программы было родительским, т.е. используется метод `Form.ShowDialog` и нужно в него передать ссылку на окно программы. Специфика заключается в том, что наше окно показывается из метода события, вызванного из API программы, и ни API программы, ни аргументы события не предоставляют доступ к текущему открытому модальному окну.

Таким образом, как получить ссылку (или handle) текущего модального окна программы?

Comment: При открытии очередного модального окна Вы используете this, Это ссылка на текущее модальное окно Кэп :).

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов Дело в том, что своё модальное окно должно быть показано из API программы и там нет ссылки на текущее открытое модальное окно программы.

Comment: Имхо, тогда есть смысл добавить в вопрос немного подробностей.

Comment: текущего модальное окно, может оказаться текущем модальным окном не вашей программы:) Пробуйте указать `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle`

Comment: А лучше - создайте аргумент с IntPtr окна, и передавайте хандл окна в своё АПИ. Тогда точно не будет проблем, что "заблокировалось не то".

Comment: @nick_n_a Так как получить handle окна, чтобы создать IntPtr?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.handle `this.Handle`. Правда... все виды Form хорошо кастятся к Control, и у Control есть свойство Enabled (что б продизаблить окно на время модальности). Возможно лучше передавать `this` чем `this.Handle` (с точки зрения ООП, т.к. Handle прийдется в чистом с# прибивать потом гвоздями к WinAPI)

Comment: @nick_n_a в методе события нет ссылки на форму, поэтому я не могу получить его `handle`.

Comment: Событие, как правило, находится в самой форме (добавляется в класс наследуемый от Form), тогда хандл можно получить у `this`. Если это не так - прийдётся пересмотреть методику написания кода, и либо менять методы верстания ПО на стандартные (как правило событие не отделяют от самой формы хоть и с# это позволяет, ввиду того что без коммуникации с формой далеко не уедешь), либо пробрасывать хандл (через аргументы или через статику или другое), либо использовать нестандартные штуки вроде MainWindowHandle (выше писал).

Comment: С точки зрения WINAPI, при вызове диалога - вызывается WndProc, и... можно всегда получив сообщение WM_CREATE - узнать дескриптор нового окна (оно не обязательно диалоговое, нужно проверять класс окна, но самый первый вызов WM_CREATE после вызова ShowDialog  должен дать окно диалога ). Возможно вам нужно это https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet./api/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc Через чистое WINAPI при работе с диалогом - всегда известен его хандл. Не видя ваш код - сложно сказать что-то больше...

Comment: Ещё вариант - тупой поиск. Перечисляем главные окна, проверяем что б PID владельца - вы, а Enabled = true. Как только два условия совпадут - вы получили нужный хандл. Как - ссылка http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531828/how-to-enumerate-all-windows-belonging-to-a-particular-process-using-net и... мне кажется это приведёт вас опять к `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle`

Comment: @nick_n_a По мойму, `GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle` дает `handle` того что вы передаёте в `Application.Run`.

Comment: Ваше модальное окно - родителя имеет? (Есть утилита spy.exe которая это показывает). Если родитель - MainWindowHandle  - то надо перечислять дочек MainWindowHandle, и найти ту, которая Enabled - это будет ваше окно. Если нет, то нужно перечислять все окна с parent = 0 - и искать по условию Enabled=true, PID = ваш. Можно применить оба метода... но у вас вероятнее всего будет одно из двух. Лучше, что б не гадать - открыть утилиту - и посмотреть в какой ветви находится ваш диалог.

Comment: Как получить модальное окно - проверить окна с parent_id = null и parent_id = MainWindowHandle, на наличие Enabled = true, и PID = ваш.